# How to automatically play next item of a listBox

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

I am using a listBox to play file from media player on my form, I am using the code below to get files in my listbox,as it retuns the file name, now I am able to play files from listBox  and now I want next item in the listbox to be played automatically after a time gap.How to do this

```
this.listBox1.DisplayMember = "Name";/*to display name on listbox*/
this.listBox1.ValueMember = "FullName";/*to fetch item value on listbox*/
listBox1.DataSource = GetFolder("..\\video\\"); /*gets folder path*/ 

private static List<FileInfo> GetFolder(string folder)
{
    List<FileInfo> fileList = new List<FileInfo>();

    foreach (FileInfo file in new DirectoryInfo(folder)
                                 .GetFiles("*.mpg",SearchOption.AllDirectories))
    {
        fileList.Add(file);
    }

    return fileList;
}
```

for listbox I am using the following code

```
private void listBox2_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{     
    Player.URL = Convert.ToString(listBox2.SelectedItem);
}
```

for listBox1 I am using the code

```
    private void listBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e )
    {

        StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter("..\\Debug\\List.txt", true);
        //Player.URL = Convert.ToString(listBox1.SelectedItem);
        string selectedItem = listBox1.Items[listBox1.SelectedIndex].ToString();


        //listView1.Items.Add(listBox1.SelectedItem.ToString());

        foreach (object o in listBox1.SelectedItems)
            sw.WriteLine(DateTime.Now + " - " + o);

        sw.Close();


    }
```

Then I am using a button to transfer selected listbox1 files to listBox2 on another form

```
   private void button1_Click_1(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        System.Text.StringBuilder sb = new System.Text.StringBuilder();
        foreach (object item in listBox1.Items)
        {
            sb.Append(item.ToString());
            sb.Append(" ");

        }


       string selectedItem = listBox1.Items[listBox1.SelectedIndex].ToString();


            //listBox2.Items.Add(listBox1.SelectedItem.ToString());
            Form3 frm = new Form3();

            foreach (int i in listBox1.SelectedIndices)
            {

                    frm.listBox2.Items.Add(listBox1.Items[i].ToString());


                frm.Show();
                this.Hide();

            }

        }
```

listbox2 code is mentioned above.

Comment: What player are you using? Can you simply hook some event that lets you know when it's completed to change the `.URI` again?

Comment: I am using axWindowsMediaPlayer

Answer (score 1):

You have to intercept the [`PlayStateChange`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd562460%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) of the player. Once you get the `int` value `8`, which is `MediaEnded`, you can play the next video in the list after the desired time gap.

**[UPDATE] - this does not work for .NET 2.0, so get the proper version for `Form3.cs` from the [EDIT] at the end of the answer**

Here's `Form3.cs` (.NET 4.5):

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using WMPLib;

namespace WindowsFormsApplication10
{
    public partial class Form3 : Form
    {
        public Form3()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            this.listBox2.DisplayMember = "Name";/*to display name on listbox*/
            this.listBox2.ValueMember = "FullName";/*to fetch item value on listbox*/
            Player.PlayStateChange += Player_PlayStateChange;
        }

        async void Player_PlayStateChange(object sender, AxWMPLib._WMPOCXEvents_PlayStateChangeEvent e)
        {
            if ((WMPLib.WMPPlayState)e.newState == WMPLib.WMPPlayState.wmppsMediaEnded)
            {
                if (listBox2.SelectedIndex + 1 < listBox2.Items.Count)
                {
                    await System.Threading.Tasks.Task.Delay(3000);
                    listBox2.SelectedItem = listBox2.Items[listBox2.SelectedIndex + 1];
                }
            }
        }

        private void listBox2_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Player.URL = Convert.ToString(listBox2.SelectedItem.GetType().GetProperty("FullName").GetValue(listBox2.SelectedItem)).ToString();
            Player.Ctlcontrols.play();
        }
    }
}
```

And here's `Form1.cs` (.NET 4.5):

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.IO;
//using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
//using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace WindowsFormsApplication10
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            this.listBox1.DisplayMember = "Name";/*to display name on listbox*/
            this.listBox1.ValueMember = "FullName";/*to fetch item value on listbox*/
            listBox1.DataSource = GetFolder("..\\video\\"); /*gets folder path*/ 
        }

        private static List<FileInfo> GetFolder(string folder)
        {
            List<FileInfo> fileList = new List<FileInfo>();
            foreach (FileInfo file in new DirectoryInfo(folder)
                                         .GetFiles("*.mpg", SearchOption.AllDirectories))
            {
                fileList.Add(file);
            }
            return fileList;
        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Form3 frm = new Form3();
            frm.FormClosed += frm_FormClosed;

            foreach (int i in listBox1.SelectedIndices)
            {
                frm.listBox2.Items.Add(new 
                { 
                    Name = ((FileInfo)listBox1.Items[i]).Name, 
                    FullName = ((FileInfo)listBox1.Items[i]).FullName 
                });
                frm.Show();
                this.Hide();
            }
        }

        void frm_FormClosed(object sender, FormClosedEventArgs e)
        {
            this.Show();
        }
    }
}
```

**[EDIT] - this should work for .NET 2.0**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using WMPLib;

namespace WindowsFormsApplication10
{
    public partial class Form3 : Form
    {
        System.Timers.Timer _timer = new System.Timers.Timer();
        object _locker = new object();

        public Form3()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            this.listBox2.DisplayMember = "Name";/*to display name on listbox*/
            this.listBox2.ValueMember = "FullName";/*to fetch item value on listbox*/
            Player.PlayStateChange += Player_PlayStateChange;

            _timer.Elapsed += _timer_Elapsed;
            _timer.Interval = 3000;

        }

        void _timer_Elapsed(object sender, System.Timers.ElapsedEventArgs e)
        {
            _timer.Stop();
            lock (_locker)
            {
                this.Invoke((MethodInvoker)delegate
                {
                    if (listBox2.SelectedIndex + 1 < listBox2.Items.Count)
                    {
                        listBox2.SelectedItem = listBox2.Items[listBox2.SelectedIndex + 1];
                    }
                });
            }
        }

        void Player_PlayStateChange(object sender, AxWMPLib._WMPOCXEvents_PlayStateChangeEvent e)
        {
            if ((WMPLib.WMPPlayState)e.newState == WMPLib.WMPPlayState.wmppsMediaEnded)
            {
                _timer.Start();
            }
            else if ((WMPLib.WMPPlayState)e.newState == WMPLib.WMPPlayState.wmppsReady)
            {
                Player.Ctlcontrols.play();
            }
        }

        private void listBox2_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Player.URL = Convert.ToString(listBox2.SelectedItem.GetType().GetProperty("FullName").GetValue(listBox2.SelectedItem, null)).ToString();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Alex I tried your code but it is showing some errors  Error 1 Invalid token 'void' in class, struct, or interface member declaration D:\.net\WindowsApplication1\WindowsApplication1\Form3.cs 52 15 WindowsApplication1
when I changed async to private it shows Error 1 No overload for method 'GetValue' takes '1' arguments D:\.net\WindowsApplication1\WindowsApplication1\Form3.cs 45 43 WindowsApplication1
and there is an error on line await also..

Comment: What errors? Have you added the player through the form's designer?

Comment: Ok, I'm going to post the whole file content. Probably there are some unmatched parantheses.

Comment: Ok, posted the code for `Form3.cs` and also added the code for `Form1.cs`.

Comment: Alex the code is not working for me bro..System.Linq and System.Threading are showing namespace error..I would like to tell that I am using visual studio 2005 for this.so is that a prob?

Comment: I'll post something that works in 2.0. My code was built for 4.5.

Comment: Hi Alex The code is now running without bug but its not playing any video as when I click on the listbox2 item to play it shows Null refrence exception was unhandeled:Object reference not set to an instance of an object. Will there be some changes in form1 also?

Comment: On which line is the exception thrown?

Comment: Ok, you should focus on how I add the items from `listBox1` to `listBox2` in the `button1_Click` method on `Form1`. I also transfer the `FullName` as a property of the list items, because that is an absolute path. When the `Player.URL` is set, I actually grab the `FullName` from the underlying object. You get an exception because you haven't updated the `button1_Click` method.

Comment: on line Player.URl and when I change it to Player.URL = Convert.ToString(listBox2.SelectedItem);it plays the video but once the media gets end it throws the exception Cross-thread operation not valid: Control 'listBox2' accessed from a thread other than the thread it was created on. on line if (listBox2.SelectedIndex + 1 < listBox2.Items.Count)

Comment: Please update the `_timer_Elapsed` method with the new content from my answer.

Comment: Hi Alex I made the changes as you said but now the index is not actually changing its Adding the next Index(means prev.index also remains selected).but the next video is not playing..If I put the  Player.Ctlcontrols.play();inside  private void listBox2_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e) its repeating the video

Comment: I believe that you might want to start a new project from scratch, add the controls on two simple forms, add the code I've posted for each form and then see if it works. Based on that, you can compare it with your own code and see where the problem lies.

Comment: Thanx for the help Alex.The code is perfectly working right now.The problem was with my listBox2 Selection mode it was set to MultiExtended in form designer..You rock man..:) Thanks for the help once again..